# Kernel regression with monotonicity constraints

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I need to fit a bivariate data using kernel regression (local polynomial regression).
It should satisfies two conditions.

- $\frac{dy}{dx_1} \geq 0$ for all $x_2$
- $\frac{dy}{dx_2} \geq 0$ for all $x_1$

How can I incorporate these two conditions into local polynomial regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shape restrictions on the kernel regression function can be imposed using various approach.

One general method was developed in [Du, Parmeter and Racine (2013)](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHrNaJrbTMAhWhnIMKHQ9IAiYQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.stat.sinica.edu.tw%2Fsstest%2Foldpdf%2FA23n317.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEXrOqeTIje9el8jetrBdYnwvwg1Q). The basic idea is to impose the constraints (here monotonicity) through weights in a generalized kernel estimator in the spirit of Hall and Huang (2001). The procedure involves solving a quadratic program with linear inequality constraints.

Another method was recently proposed in [Horowitz and Lee (2015)](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZ_JqGtLTMAhXJ8z4KHcv4BYsQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifs.org.uk%2Fuploads%2Fcemmap%2FJoel%2520L%2520Horowitz.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEYFvbmVhA1498gxBMrIxaTZItqaA). The idea is to estimate the unrestricted kernel function, then evaluate what constraints are binding, and finally re-estimate the kernel function under the restrictions found and ignore all others.

Other recent papers study shape restrictions in econometrics. Among others, [Chernozukov, Newey and Santos (2015)](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjm98eitbTMAhUJhYMKHWghBKoQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1509.06311&usg=AFQjCNHU0y4AVSUuXLHS9KrljQpWIqyo5Q&bvm=bv.120853415,d.amc) for conditional moment restriction models although I find it to be a difficult read.